# Nestjs GRPC Service method without parameters

Tags: typescript, nestjs, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm learning how to build a micro services architecture by nestjs and gRPC
I create an API to get data from another service, and it doesn't need any argument.

So I use `google.protobuf.Empty` and let validate interface function keep empty as code below.

`contractAddress.proto`

```
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
syntax = "proto3";

package contractAddress;

service ContractAddressService {
  rpc getAllContractAddress (google.protobuf.Empty) returns (GetAllContractAddressResponse);
}

message GetAllContractAddressResponse {
  repeated string data = 1;
}
```

`grpc.interface.ts`

```
export interface ContractServiceClient {
  getAllContractAddress(): Observable<GetAllContractAddressResponse>;
}
```

`contract.controller.ts`

```
  @Inject('CONTRACTADDRESS_PACKAGE')
  private client: ClientGrpc;

  onModuleInit(): void {
    this.svc = this.client.getService<ContractServiceClient>(
      'ContractAddressService',
    );
  }

  @Get()
  getContractAddres() {
    return this.svc.getAllContractAddress();
  }
```

But I encountered the error when I called this api.
Does it mean I need to add argument absolutely？
I have tried that adding argument, and it works well.

```
[Nest] 77656  - 09/12/2022, 5:54:19 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Incorrect arguments passed
Error: Incorrect arguments passed
    at ServiceClientImpl.checkOptionalUnaryResponseArguments (/Users/champerwu/Documents/Project/naos-fin-interview/naos-api/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:224:15)
    at ServiceClientImpl.makeUnaryRequest (/Users/champerwu/Documents/Project/naos-fin-interview/naos-api/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:271:35)
    at ServiceClientImpl.getAllContractAddress (/Users/champerwu/Documents/Project/naos-fin-interview/naos-api/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/make-client.ts:189:15)
    at Observable._subscribe (/Users/champerwu/Documents/Project/naos-fin-interview/naos-api/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client/client-grpc.js:177:35)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (/Users/champerwu/Documents/Project/naos-fin-interview/naos-api/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Observable.ts:245:19)
    at /Users/champerwu/Documents/Project/naos-fin-interview/naos-api/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Observable.ts:235:18
    at Object.errorContext (/Users/champerwu/Documents/Project/naos-fin-interview/naos-api/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/util/errorContext.ts:29:5)
    at Observable.subscribe (/Users/champerwu/Documents/Project/naos-fin-interview/naos-api/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Observable.ts:221:5)
    at /Users/champerwu/Documents/Project/naos-fin-interview/naos-api/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/lastValueFrom.ts:59:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: I tried `this.svc.getAllContractAddress({});` `getAllContractAddress({}): Observable<GetAllContractAddressResponse>;`
and it works successfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to provide a message argument in all cases. `google.protobuf.Empty` is a predefined message type with no fields, but it is not otherwise special, and using it does not trigger any special code generation. You still need to provide an empty message object.